# How can I migrate data from MySQL without the login to the database?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a school project and making a student profiling system for another school. What they want me to is to reuse the database of their registrar's office and at the same time have a local database for the computer the student profiling system will be running on. So no problem right?

They're using an old system and no longer have contact with the people who made it and they don't have the source code or the login credentials for the database. Is there any ethical way for me to get past this roadblock or am I stuck? If I am stuck, what other options do I have rather than populating a new database?

It would be very unprofessional for me to find a way to break it(high doubt it) and snoop around their computers. I'm going to use PostgreSQL by the way.

Comment: Please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: I did not know you could do that. Thank you, sir. Would you mind posting it as an answer? I'd like to give you those points for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record there is documentation at dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

It details how to reset things and get back on track.

One is assuming that this link is OK as some folks do not link links as an answer.

Comment: Ed, I appreciate this was originally post as an comment, but as it stands this is *really* not an answer. Do you have the time to include a few basic points from the link?